# How can I preload records with parent-child self-references using Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: nhibernate, tree, castle-activerecord

My SQL table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Page (
    Id int primary key,
    ParentId int, -- refers to Page.Id
    Title varchar(255),
    Content ntext
)
```

and maps to the following class in my ActiveRecord model:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Page {

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("Parent")]
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [HasMany(typeof(Page), "Parent", "Page")]
    public IList<Page> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using ActiveRecord to retrieve the tree roots using the following code:

```
var rootPages = new SimpleQuery<Page>(@"from Page p where p.Parent is null");
return(rootPages.Execute());
```

This gives me the correct object graph, but a SQL Profiler trace shows that child pages are being loaded by a separate query for every non-leaf node in the tree.

How can I get ActiveRecord to load the whole lot up front `("SELECT * FROM Page")` and then sort the in-memory objects to give me the required parent-child relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to fetch the entire table, then filter the result.  This is pretty easy, if you are using linq.

```
var AllPages = ActiveRecordMediator<Page>.FindAll();
var rootPages = AllPages.Where(p => p.Parent == null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var rootPages = new SimpleQuery<Page>(@"from Page p left join fetch p.Children where p.Parent is null");
return(rootPages.Execute());
```

This will cause the Children collection of each Page in the result set to be populated out during the initial query, which should reduce your overall query load to a single query.

Comment: This will only load the first level of children.  Any tree with a depth greater than 2 will still exibit the N+1 issue.

Comment: True. But the questioner's example doesn't have a second level of children. You'd need to design the query to suit the specific circumstances on each occasion. AFAIK there's no one-size-fits all approach.